# Official nomenclature for human roles in a Kubernetes-based shop?

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, kubernetes-helm

Is there something like the old J2EE Platform Roles but for Kubernetes?  It doesn't have to map 1:1 to these old roles of course, but I would like to have a reference to answer questions like, "The person who runs `helm install` and is responsible for knowing what all the options do is called _________?" Or, "The person who designs the autoscaling policy is called _______?"  Or even, "The person who is responsible that all of the docker images used in the enterprise have been patched with the latest CVE vulnerability fixes is called ________?"  Is there a standard nomenclature for this sort of thing?  Where is it?

Thanks,

Ed

[image: J2EE Platform Roles]

Answer (score 1):

The closest to this is Kubernetes [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/). You can create roles and bind the roles to groups/users/service accounts. You will have to do so heavy lifting in terms of defining the specific roles that suit your organizations and what types of permissions.

If you are looking for an audit trail, you can look at [Auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, my question still applies even when not using RBAC.  The "roles" I'm talking about are broader, "human" roles.  For example, the "software developer" role is the person who writes, tests, and certifies the correctness of the code running in a pod.  This is all about "who does what" in a kubernetes shop.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a specific solution for that